# Use RVM With Lighttpd CGI

Tags: ruby, cgi, rvm, lighttpd

I have a very simple CGI server set up with lighttpd's `mod_cgi` and I have a multi-user install of RVM. How can I set up lighttpd to use RVM's ruby and its default gems?

I tried adding the lighttpd user to the rvm group, but that seems useless since `rvm use ...` only works from a login shell (and you can't log in as lighttpd).

I also tried just setting

```
".rb"  => "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby"
```

in `/etc/lighttpd/conf.d/cgi.conf`. Then Ruby scripts work with CGI, but I still can't require any gems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use RVM generated wrappers, which bundle up the whole environment specifically for such a purpose. The instructions for [using RVM with cron](https://rvm.io/integration/cron) are very helpful since lighttpd CGI runs in a similarly barren no-login environment.

In my case, it was as simple as changing `cgi.assign` in `cgi.conf` to

```
".rb" => "/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.2/ruby"
```